# How to implement MASE (Mean Absolute Scaled Error) in python

Tags: python, statistics

I have Predicted values and Actual values, and I can calculate Mean Absolute Percentage Error by doing:

```
abs(Predicted-Actual)/ Predicted *100
```

How do I calculate MASE with respect to my Predicted and Actual values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **M**ean **A**bsolute **S**caled **E**rror (**MASE**) is calculated by subtracting the forecasted or predicted value from the actual value divided by the average forecast error where the actual value from the prior step is used as the prediction or forecast.

Here is the equation as a `list-comprehension`:

```
mase = numpy.mean([abs(Actual[i] - Predicted[i]) / (abs(Actual[i] - Actual[i - 1]) / len(Actual) - 1) for i in range(1, len(Actual))])
```

Here is the equation as a function:

```
def MASE(Actual, Predicted):
    values = []
    for i in range(1, len(Actual)):
        values.append(abs(Actual[i] - Predicted[i]) / (abs(Actual[i] - Actual[i - 1]) / len(Actual) - 1))
    return numpy.mean(values)
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer if anyone can confirm this.
Thank you.

Comment: @azazelspeaks here's the wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error).

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet from the N-Beats authors' implementation, I think this is the correct version:

```
np.mean(np.abs(forecast - outsample)) / np.mean(np.abs(insample[:-frequency] - insample[frequency:]))
```

Src: https://github.com/ServiceNow/N-BEATS/blob/c746a4f13ffc957487e0c3279b182c3030836053/common/metrics.py#L24

Comment: Does have the advantage of being vectorized, while the accepted answer is not.